# Does .Net Core 2.1 support HTTP/2 requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc

I am working to gRPC in my .Net Core 2.1 application, But when i send a request the server throws an error stating

Connection id "" bad request data: "Unrecognized HTTP version: 'HTTP/2.0'

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Unrecognized HTTP version: 'HTTP/2.0'
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.RejectUnknownVersion(Byte* version, Int32 length)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler handler, Byte* data, Int32 length)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler handler, ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition&

Comment: if i am not mistaken it was announced in version 2.2 and even there you need to enable it. You can double check the 2.2 release notes.

Comment: Yeah i think i should migrate to 2.2 first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please checkout documentation here to enable http/2 in kestrel:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#http2-support

Comment: thats the wrong version. when you switch version to 2.1, http2 no longer exists

Comment: Have you tried this: https://dotnetthoughts.net/enable-http2-on-kestrel/

Comment: Yes, i believe i need to upgrade the sdk

Comment: @Umang I am getting the same error even after updating to 2.2 and adding these configurations